# Linq Sum Group by without decimals

Tags: c#, decimal, number-formatting

I have this Group by Sum LinQ but it give me a result with alot of decimals is there a way to round up the number? to not display the decimals?
This is my LinQ:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => new //here you count your total
                                            {
                                            Rid = x.Rid,
                                            Total = x.Total * x.Cantidad
                                            })
                                            .GroupBy(l => l.Rid) //and then grouping
                                            .Select(z => new
                                            {
                                            Turno = z.Key,
                                            Total = z.Sum(l => l.Total)
                                            }))
                                        {
                                        <input value="@item" />
                                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "round up", you can use `Decimal.Round()` or `Math.Floor()`, `Math.Ceiling()`.

```
Total = Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0);
```

Comment: excelent thanks this was the approach i was looking for